# Python shelve able to create but not open shelf

Tags: python, shelve

I'm having a strange experience. I'm running python3.5.3 on debian, installed through the official repositories. I have a few objects that I store in a shelf as follows

```
with shelve.open(filename,'c') as shelf:
    shelf['lists'] = (bus1,bus2)
    shelf['N'] = N
    shelf['wtfun'] = mywtfun.__name__
    shelf['g'] = g
    shelf['svs'] = mysvs
```

It saves it as filename.db when I do this. Running file on this in the unix prompt tells me it is a Berkeley database. I do have the bsddb module installed.

Then when I try:

```
s1 = shelve.open(filename)
```

I get the following error:

```
<ipython-input-100-171f41c7dda0> in <module>()
----> 1 s1 = shelve.open('busemanns-runs-30000-N-1000-absnormal-2018-04-20T22:14:18.439245.shelf.db')

/usr/lib/python3.5/shelve.py in open(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
241    <ipython-input-100-171f41c7dda0> in <module>()
----> 1 s1 = shelve.open('busemanns-runs-30000-N-1000-absnormal-2018-04-20T22:14:18.439245.shelf.db')

/usr/lib/python3.5/shelve.py in open(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
    241     """
    242
--> 243     return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)

/usr/lib/python3.5/shelve.py in __init__(self, filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
225     def __init__(self, filename, flag='c', protocol=None, writeback=False):
226         import dbm
--> 227         Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
228
229

/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/__init__.py in open(file, flag, mode)
 86     elif result == "":
 87         # db type cannot be determined
---> 88         raise error[0]("db type could not be determined")
 89     elif result not in _modules:
 90         raise error[0]("db type is {0}, but the module is not "

error: db type could not be determined
 """
    242
--> 243     return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)

/usr/lib/python3.5/shelve.py in __init__(self, filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
    225     def __init__(self, filename, flag='c', protocol=None, writeback=False):
226         import dbm
--> 227         Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
228
229

/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/__init__.py in open(file, flag, mode)
 86     elif result == "":
 87         # db type cannot be determined
---> 88         raise error[0]("db type could not be determined")
 89     elif result not in _modules:
 90         raise error[0]("db type is {0}, but the module is not "

error: db type could not be determined
```

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty weird, but the problem is fixed if I *omit the .db* from the end of the filename. That is, I was running

```
shelve.open("filename.db")
```

and *this was failing*. If you have any sort of autocomplete in your python shell, it seems to pick it up with the `.db` extension. To get it to work, I had to run

```
shelve.open("filename")
```